# How do I make this Plot smaller in visual studio code?

Tags: plot, visual-studio-code, julia

I have a problem with the size of the plot that is on the right side of the picture bellow. I've tried to make it smaller using ctrl and - , but it made everything smaller. How do I make just the plot window smaller so I could see the whole thing?

Here is my code:

```
using Plots
t=0:1:10
y = sin.(t)
p=plot(t,y,xtick=1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: Pleas provide your code and data within the question and not as image. Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65430669/edit) button to edit your question. Also try to describe what have you done and what problems you face in better details.

Comment: @Ruli Thank you for your suggestion. I'm a new user so I'm still struggling a bit on how to format the question. I tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `plot!(size=...)` as here:

```
using Plots
t=0:10
p=plot(t,sin.(t),xtick=1:10)
plot!(size=(350,200))
```

[image]

Yet another option, if you need interactivity, is to select an interactive backend. For an example you could try `Plots.plotlyjs()` before issuing the `plot` command.